# Mapping a DB column name to a Bean property using annotations in Java Spring

Tags: java, annotations

the problem I am trying to solve is to map a DB column name to a bean property name in a Spring project. I cannot use JPA, or Hibernate. Basically I want the db layer to know to write to the bean using the column mapping, but consumers of the bean to use the bean property name.

A custom annotation might do it, but I am having a hard time finding documentation for what I want to do, which might mean thats its not a good idea.

A mapper of some sort might do it, but I like the idea of the annotation because then the mapping is documented in the bean.

Given a bean:

```
public class ServiceBean
{
    @ColumnMapping(value = "service_name")
    private String  serviceName;
    @ColumnMapping(value = "service_desc")
    private String  serviceDesc;

    public String getServiceName()
    {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public void setServiceName(String serviceName)
    {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    public String getServiceDesc()
    {
        return serviceDesc;
    }

    public void setServiceDesc(String serviceDesc)
    {
        this.serviceDesc = serviceDesc;
    }
}
```

I think the start of the annotation definition looks like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface ColumnMapping
{
    String value();
}
```

I might be in the weeds here.

Comment: *Why* can you not use JPA? How are you expecting the ORM to happen, since you haven't showed it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MyBatis](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/) framework with following mapping configuration:

```
<resultMap id="MyResultMap" type="ServiceBean">
  <result column="service_name" property="serviceName" javaType="String" />
  <result column="service_desc" property="serviceDesc" javaType="String" />
</resultMap>
```

It is a lightweight SQL persistence and mapping framework that can be easily integrated in a Spring architecture.
The current version (v3) now supports annotations ([see here](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html)).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I will check that out. Appreciate the comment.